# Size issue when reading HDFS with rhdfs library

Tags: r, hdfs

I'm trying to read some HDFS files (csv text) from R using the rhdfs library. I'm using the following code:

```
hdfs.init()
f = hdfs.file(hdfspath,"r")
m = hdfs.read(f)
> object.size(m)
131112 bytes
```

The issue arises when I check the size of the objects that are read from HDFS. I'm only reading a fraction of the records in the HDFS filesystem. No matter the size of the original HDFS file, I'm only getting 131112 bytes (or around 2^17 bytes). I've tried changing the buffersize parameter but without success. Is there any specific parameter that should be set?

I found a similar issue here [1], but there is no answer.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

[1] https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/rhdfs/issues/8

Comment: Could you please show in the question the code and result of your attempt to check the size? I'm pretty sure I know the answer, but I'm hesitant to say it without seeing that first.

Comment: Thanks @Hack-R. I've edited the question adding the init function I'm also using and the size check. Apart from that, the only thing I'm also doing is setting the HADOOP_CMD and HADOOP_HOME variables.

I don't think it's related to the issue, but I'm using a Hortonworks framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by specifying the amount of bytes that I want to read and which byte to start (parameters "n" and "start"). It seems that these parameters need to be explicitly set in order to read the whole file.

```
f = hdfs.file(hdfspath,"r")
m = hdfs.read(f, start = 0, n = hdfs.ls(hdfspath)$size)
```

Where "hdfspath" points to the HDFS file.